# How exactly do I create a multicolumn listbox in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

What I'm looking for is a list box that has multiple columns for example a list box for books where each row would have a title, price, author.

Bonus points for anyone who can give me some pointers on how exactly I can add items to the list as well. I'm guessing

```
 listBox1.Items.Add("Harry Potter", "JK Rowling", 5.99);
```

wont work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into the same question before and turned to ListViews instead.  Something like:

```
Public Class Form1
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim lv As New ListView
    With lv
        .View = View.Details
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .Columns.Add("Title")
        .Columns.Add("Author")
        .Columns.Add("Price")
    End With

    Me.Controls.Add(lv)
    lv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    lv.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({"Harry Potter", "J.K. Rowling", 5.99}))
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to change property:

```
Me.listBox1.MultiColumn = True
```

to add single:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Item")
```

to add multi:

```
With Me.listBox1
    Me.listBox1.ColumnCount = 2
    .AddItem
    .List(i, 0) = "something for first column"
    .List(i, 1) = "something for second column"
    i = i + 1
end with
```

Learn more about listbox [1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_listbox.htm) [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Now you should really use ListView:

```
    'Add Three Columns To ListView 2
    ListView2.Columns.Add("Zodiac", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center) 'Column 1
    ListView2.Columns.Add("From", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left) 'Column 2
    ListView2.Columns.Add("To", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Right) 'Column 3

    'Show Small Images Next To Zodiac Sign
    ListView2.SmallImageList = ImageList2

    'Declare Array For ListView Items
    Dim arrLVItem(11) As ListViewItem

    Dim j As Integer 'Loop Counter

    'Loop Through Each ListViewItem Array Item
    For j = 0 To arrLVItem.Length - 1

        'Initialize ListViewItem Array
        arrLVItem(j) = New ListViewItem

        'Add Text To First ListView Item - The Zodiac Sign
        arrLVItem(j).SubItems(0).Text = arrZodiac(j)

        'Add From and To SubItems On Zodiac ListView Item
        arrLVItem(j).SubItems.Add(arrFrom(j))
        arrLVItem(j).SubItems.Add(arrTo(j))

        'Connect ListView Item With Its Associated Picture
        arrLVItem(j).ImageIndex = j

    Next j

    'Add Completed Arrays To [ListView][3]
    ListView2.Items.AddRange(arrLVItem)
```

Comment: No no. According to Microsoft *"A multicolumn ListBox places items into as many columns as are needed to make vertical scrolling unnecessary."*. The [ListBox.MultiColumn Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does not turn the ListBox into a kind of grid.

Answer (score 2):

You can add any type of object to list boxes. Create a class containing the desired properties and override the ToString method. The list box uses it to display the items.

```
Public Class Book
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Author As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} by {1} at {2:c}", Title, Author, Price)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then

```
Dim p = New Person With {.Title = "Harry Potter", .Author = "JK Rowling", Price = 5.99D}
listBox1.Items.Add(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Me.ListBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ListBox()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    ' 
    ' listBox1
    ' 
    Me.ListBox1.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.ListBox1.HorizontalScrollbar = True
    Me.ListBox1.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"Item 1, column 1", "Item 2, column 1", "Item 3, column 1", "Item 4, column 1", "Item 5, column 1", "Item 1, column 2", "Item 2, column 2", "Item 3, column 2"})
    Me.ListBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.ListBox1.MultiColumn = True
    Me.ListBox1.Name = "listBox1"
    Me.ListBox1.ScrollAlwaysVisible = True
    Me.ListBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(120, 95)
    Me.ListBox1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidth = 85
    ' 
    ' Form1
    ' 
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(292, 273)
    Me.Controls.Add(ListBox1)
    Me.Name = "Form1"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
End Sub
```

Comment: by the way - I wouldn't use a listbox, I'd use a datagrid but it depends what you want to do......

Answer (score 0):

I was just struggling with the same problm. Eactually an easy fix. You just need to put plus between each one of them and they will stay on the same row. If you want space inbetween them, just add "\t". So:
listBox1.Items.Add("Harry Potter" + "\t" + "JK Rowling" + "\t" + 5.99);