# Populate ListBox from SQL Server table

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am going crazy here. Trying to teach myself vb.net. I come from a vba background and have spent hours trying to create a two column list box from a T-SQL query on a numeric table.

I can get it to list one column, but that's it.

I don't suppose anyone can tell me where I am going wrong? Am I even using the best method?

```
    MsgBox("hello")
    LblTest.Text = "Hello World"
    LblTest.ForeColor = Color.Red

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=CHRISTINES-DESK\SQL2008EXPRESS;
    InitialCatalog=Trading;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=########"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim selectQuery As String = "SELECT Breakeven.Spend, Breakeven.Gain FROM levels"
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection)

    connection.Open()
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Spend"
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Cost"

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

    Me.ListBox1.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.ListBox1.ScrollAlwaysVisible = True
    Me.ListBox1.MultiColumn = True

    While reader.Read()
            Dim item1 As Decimal = reader.GetDecimal(0)
            Dim item2 As Decimal = reader.GetDecimal(1)

            ListBox1.Items.Add(New MyItem(item1, item2))
            Debug.Print(item1 & " - " & item2)
    End While

    reader.Close()
    connection.Close()


In form:

        ListBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.Menu
        ListBox1.ColumnWidth = 80
        ListBox1.FormattingEnabled = True
        ListBox1.ItemHeight = 15
        ListBox1.Location = New Point(18, 59)
        ListBox1.MultiColumn = True
        ListBox1.Name = "ListBox1"
        ListBox1.Size = New Size(310, 334)
        ListBox1.TabIndex = 2
```

Tried everything I could find - even chatgpt for an answer, I can't solve it.

Comment: Use a `ListView` or `DataGridView` instead.

Comment: A ListBox doesn't have columns. Technically it can but that just means that the single list of values overflows horizontally instead of vertically. You should be using a DataGridView for multiple columns. You could use a ListView but it doesn't support data binding and is not an actual grid control.

Answer (score 0):

Like this question, I suggest to use listview.

[How exactly do I create a multicolumn listbox in Visual Basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801384/how-exactly-do-i-create-a-multicolumn-listbox-in-visual-basic)